# Confluence Expand vs. UI Expand

Tags: macros, confluence

Simple question: what's the difference between **expand** and **ui expand**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered a significant difference involving behavior.

UI Expand allows you to use expandable code blocks inside of it.  Expanding and collapsing the nested code block does not affect the behavior of UI expand, whereas you cannot do this with regular Expand -- expanding/collapsing the nested code block also collapses the Expand, which is extremely annoying, and is one of the reasons why I'm looking into this in the first place.

If I come across anything else, I'll edit this entry.

**EDIT:** Another difference: using "#expand-(name of UI-expand)" in your URL goes to the UI-expand (as though it was an anchor) and expands it.  This ONLY works with UI-expand; the regular expand will NOT do this.  (It is for this reason why I included anchors before my expand macro, but apparently ui-expand does not need anchors.  Even so, it only goes to the anchor; it does not expand the actual expand macro without any coding.)